# Java Error 'Unable to create initial connections of pool' during startup

Tags: java

I have problem with running Java SpringBoot Application, during startup i get some errors like this:
what's wrong with it?

```
2017-08-30 17:20:41.790 ERROR 5048 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/app_db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-193]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.193.jar:1.4.193]



    2017-08-30 17:20:41.795  WARN 5048 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource


    org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/app_db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-193]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What do you not understand from the error message? I think it gives well explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved, i working on Windows, application was written on linux, thats the reason